# How to do the following integration?

Tags: numerical-integration

When I **Integrate** the function

```
fx = Sin[theta]^2*Exp[-(a/Sin[theta]^2)]
Integrate[fx, {theta, 0, (Pi)/2}]
```

> [a is a constant]

it gives the warning `"NIntegrate::inumr: "The integrand E^(-thres\Csc[theta]^2)\ Sin[theta]^2 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,2.35619}}."`

How can I get the conclusive simplified result?

Comment: No. Thres is a constant

Comment: @Nasser yeah, I have mentioned it below. Anyway let me modify the question

Comment: your updated question runs with no problem. Try with clean kernel?  screen shot. 12.3.1   ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cE08P.png)

Comment: @Nasser can you tell me now? I have modified the question, in this case, how can I get the result? Now it is normal integration.

Comment: You can't possibly get the warning you give as there is no longer a "thres" in the `NIntegrate` and you've switched to `Integrate` (which might not have a closed-form solution).

Comment: Integrate can't do it. I tried few other integrators, and they can't do it. So it looks like there is not antiderivative for this. Stick to `NIntegrate` as you had before, I would say. This is too hard to do analytically.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Nasser

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve this Integration analytically?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/257869/how-to-solve-this-integration-analytically)

Comment: @user64494 both questions are different. This question is using Mathematica. Another question is solving analytically.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like:

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sin ^2(x) \exp \left(-\frac{a}{\sin ^2(x)}\right) \, dx=\frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{a} e^{-a} \sqrt{\pi }+\frac{1}{4} (1-2 a) \pi  \text{erfc}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)$$

Using a `MellinTransform`:

```
SOL = InverseMellinTransform[Integrate[
MellinTransform[Sin[x]^2*Exp[-(a/Sin[x]^2)], a, s] // 
PowerExpand, {x, 0, Pi/2}, Assumptions -> {a > 0, Re[s] > 0}], s, a] // FullSimplify

(*1/2 Sqrt[a] E^-a Sqrt[\[Pi]] + 1/4 (1 - 2 a) \[Pi] Erfc[Sqrt[a]]*)
```

We can check:

```
f[a_] := NIntegrate[Sin[x]^2*Exp[-(a/Sin[x]^2)], {x, 0, Pi/2}]
Plot[{f[a], SOL}, {a, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Red, {Dashed, Black}},
PlotLegends -> {"Numeric Integration", "Analytical solution"}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

One way is to include an assumption about $a$.  This evaluation took about 60 seconds on my desktop computer.

```
$Version

(* 12.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 14, 2020)  *)


fθ = Sin[theta]^2*Exp[-(a/Sin[theta]^2)];
g1 = Integrate[fθ, {theta, 0, π/2}, Assumptions -> 0 < a]

(*  1/2 Sqrt[a] E^-a Sqrt[π] + 1/4 (1 - 2 a) π Erfc[Sqrt[a]]  *)
```

Another way is to do a change of variables from polar to cartesian.  That is, let  $\sin\theta \rightarrow y$.  Then $d\theta \rightarrow \frac{dy}{dy/d\theta}$.  This evaluation took about 4 seconds.

```
jacdet = 1/Cos[theta];
fy = (fθ * jacdet) /. theta -> ArcSin[y];
g2 = Integrate[fy, {y, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> 0 < a]

(*  1/2 Sqrt[a] E^-a Sqrt[π] + 1/4 (1 - 2 a) π Erfc[Sqrt[a]]  *)
```

Numerically,

```
h[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[Sin[theta]^2*Exp[-(a/Sin[theta]^2)], {theta, 0, π/2}]

Table[g1, {a, 5}] // N
Array[h, 5]


(*  {0.202482, 0.0624102, 0.0202436, 0.00674643, 0.00228717}  *)
(*  {0.202482, 0.0624102, 0.0202436, 0.00674643, 0.00228717}  *)
```